# Custom validator doesn't appear when input takes invalid value

Tags: angular, typescript

My validator should make sure that the user doesn't try putting a value less than 1 or greater than 20 but the validator doesn't show up if I put 21 or -1 for example.

This is what's in my component's class:

```
export function invalidCount(value: number): ValidatorFn {
  if(value > 0 && value <= 20) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      console.log("error");
      return {'badValue': value};
    };
  }
}

export class Foo implements OnInit {
//other important code related to @Component...

    count: number = 1;
    control = new FormControl(this.count, invalidCount(this.count));
}
```

Then in the template I have

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Choose a value</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="count" required min="1" 
            max="20" 
            [formControl]="control">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your validator function as below :

```
  count: number = 1;

  control = new FormControl(this.count, this.invalidCount)

  invalidCount(control: AbstractControl) {
    if(control.value > 0 && control.value <= 20) {
      return null;
    } else{
        return {'badValue': control.value};
    };
  }
```

I have created the stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prrdva